# Method Range failure

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to generate a function to pull data from one spreadsheet to another but keep getting the global method range error. It's line 4 which generates the error. Any solutions?

```
Sub potential()

    'Add hours for potential work to generate function

    Worksheets("Resource Forecast").Select

    ***p = Range("Potential Person").End(xlDown).Row - Range("Potential Person").Row*** (error line)

    Worksheets("Resourcing Sit-Rep").Select

    For k = 1 To p

        For j = 1 To 187
            If Range("hours").Offset(k, j).Value > 0 Then

            Sheets("Resource Forecast").Select
                Val5 = Range("person").Offset(k, 1).Value
                Val6 = Range("person").Offset(k).Value
                Val7 = Range("hours").Offset(k, j).Value
                Val8 = Range("date").Offset(0, j).Value

            Sheets("Resourcing Sit-Rep").Select
                A = Range("Leader").Offset(0, 2).End(xlDown).Row - Range("Leader").Offset(0, 2).Row + 1

                Range("Leader").Offset(A, 2).Formula = Sheets("Resource Forecast").Range("Project_Number").Value & " (" & Sheets("Resource Forecast").Range("Project_Name").Value & ") - " & Val5 & " POTENTIAL WORK"
                Range("Leader").Offset(A, 3).Formula = Val6
                Range("Leader").Offset(A, 4).Formula = Val7 / 7.5
                Range("Leader").Offset(A, 5).Formula = Val8

             Else

             End If

        Next j

    Next k
    Range("Leader").Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 2).AutoFill Destination:=Range("A4", Cells(Range("Leader").Offset(0, 2).End(xlDown).Row, 2)), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `End(xlDown)` from that line.

To do what you want you can use the following (using indirect referencing):

```
Range("Area2").Cells(1, 1).Row - Range("Area1").Cells(1, 1).Row - Range("Area1").Rows.Count
```

Here, you just count amount of rows between first row of `Area1` and first row of `Area2`, then you subtract from this amount of rows in the area.

Comment: I'm now getting a subscript out of range for the line above it?

Comment: Did you change the names ("Area1"...) in the `Range` function?

Comment: Nope only changed the range part

Comment: What are you trying to do with that line?

Comment: If you want just amount of rows use expression`.Rows.Count`, where expression is `Range` object.

Comment: Search in a spreadsheet for data under the column "Potential Person". The data would be strings of someones name, a task then a number representing hours

Comment: The number of rows will vary depending on how many data sets are entered

Comment: I asked for a purpose for that exact line :) not the goal of whole macro.

Comment: Oh sorry, that line is just to get the number of rows of data that need to be processed

Comment: So, since it's the same range, your problem will be solved by using `Range("Potential Person").Rows.Count`, instead of what you using.

Comment: Back to the original error. This is one tricky bit of code. I've tried isolating it and running it individually but no luck

Comment: Try renaming the range to "PotentialPerson", space might be causing the errors.

Comment: No luck. I will try and write the code again but thanks for your help Michal